# Wicket - anchor tag for a dynamic text

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

i would like to know if its possible to have a clickable link for a dynamic text.

I have tried by using the anchor tag with some wicket id and adding an onclick behavior to it, i could see the text with link on my screen but the onclick call of t he link was never triggered.
What could possibly be the issue?

i did something like this:

```
String someTextMessage = "Hey!!! <a wicket:id='printLink'>Click Here</a> now.";
Lable message = new Lable("messageLable", someTextMessage);
message.setEscapeModelStrings(true);
Link printLink = new Link("printLink") {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
       System.out.println("inside onClick");
    }
};
this.add(printLink);
this.add(message);
```

i used this wicket id and added it to the page and attached an onclick behavior to this.
I have checked t he firebug console but there was no onclick call made for the link's click.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [Link.setAnchor(Component)](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/Link.html#setAnchor(org.apache.wicket.Component)) method.
Don't forget to setOutputMarkupId to true for the component you want to jump to.

```
Label message = new Label("messageLable", "Anchor!");
message.setOutputMarkupId(true);
this.add(message);

Link printLink = new Link("printLink") {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        System.out.println("inside onClick");
    }
};
printLink.setAnchor(message);
this.add(printLink);
```

Don't try to add wicket components by appending html with "wicket:id" in some kind of component. It won't work.